# Are there known limitations with the WCF Test Client app?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

This has happened a couple of times to me know. If I add to many OperationContract's to a ServiceContract, the WCF Test Client app throws an exception:

"Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata."

In the details it continues:

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from . The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.

If I remove a couple of operation contracts then everything is fine. Outside of the test client is also fine.

Comment: there is, I dont know if its related to yours though.  I had a problem with a huge contract definition, but i dont think i got a 400 error.  Mine had to do with a limit on the size of the definition being transmitted.  Give me a sec and I will see what i did to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.

These were the offending lines:

```
<OperationContract(), FaultContract(GetType(WcfService.Common.DefaultFaultContract))> _
Function GetJobSubTypesForJobTypeList(ByVal jobTypeList As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)) As List(Of JobSubTypeOfJobTypeDTO)

<OperationContract(), FaultContract(GetType(WcfService.Common.DefaultFaultContract))> _
Function GetActivityTypesForJobTypeList(ByVal jobTypeList As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)) As List(Of ActivityTypeOfJobTypeDTO)
```

It turned out that we were missing setters in the return types (DTO) and a default constructor.

Comment: where did you get these lines?

Comment: Sorry, two years ago at a different job -- can't remember

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more specific about what kinds of operations you have to remove from the service contract to make it work?

Here are some known limitations in the [WcfTestClient.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) tool that comes with the .NET Framework 3.5 SDK. Note that all of these issues have been fixed in the version that ships with .NET 3.5 SP1.

- The client does not maintain a **session** with the invoked service. All calls are made on new proxy instances
- The auto-generated **configuration file** for the client proxy can be viewed but not edited
- Services using the **XML Serializer** instead of of the Data Contract Serializer cannot be invoked
- Services using **Message Contracts** cannot be invoked

Answer (score 0):

This is what i had to add to my devenv.exe.config in order to get my WCF Test Client to work with a very large service.  I then had to restart my IDE.  This may not be what you are looking for, but i hope it helps.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="MyBinding">
        <textMessageEncoding>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </textMessageEncoding>
        <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="http"/>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the weirdest problems I've come across. You might have to review your code and look out for problems such as:

```
Private _NetPay As Boolean
<DataMember()> _
Public Property NetPay() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _Amount = 0
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _NetPay = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I had defined a DataMember as the above. Notice the return statment. It is trying to return a computed value. I removed this data member; it worked fine.